# Change the language of paint.net UI on opening

Tags: localization, paint.net

In my code I'm opening paint.net programmatically on button click so I can pass a specific file path to it using start arguments, now I need to pass an argument that represents a specific language so paint.net UI will be opened in this language, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no command line argument for that, but you can set the registry key just before launching the application:

HKCU\Software\Paint.NET\LanguageName
(en-US for US English, JA for Japanese, etc.)

You can also find more languages [on the forum](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/forum/5-translation-and-localization/).